# How to move widgets to other widgets in flutter?

Tags: flutter-layout

There is a screen with 1 or 2 rows of empty cells at the top and 2 rows with letters. How can I make it so that when I click on a letter from the bottom row, it moves to a free cell from left to right?

Do I need to use Stack? Or is there any way to move widgets (containers) by coordinates?

If I use Stack, will it be possible to attackpate for different screens?
[First screen with empty cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJqZy.png)

[First screen with a filled cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0zWl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [local_hero](https://pub.dev/packages/local_hero) package.